# Strange sed command

Tags: sed

I was trying to [install docker in Ubuntu](http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit), and following the instructions I have come across a very strange `sed` command which I do not understand (this seems to be used to set-up bash autocompletion for docker):

```
sudo sed -i '$acomplete -F _docker docker' /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.io
```

What is that command doing? The `-i` command means in-place editing, but what does the `$acomplete -F _docker docker` mean? The `$` is matching the last line, but what is it doing? I do not even recognize any sed command there! For example, a substitution command would look like:

```
$s/in/out/
```

Could somebody explain that expression for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appends `complete -F _docker docker` to the file.

From sed's manual:

> a \
>
> text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

Comment: looks strange, I think, why not `echo >>/path/to/file`

Comment: What trick of `sed` is using to do that? Could you point me to the relevant part of the documentation?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide I think the advantage of it is that whether the file ends with a newline or not it would still append a new line to it. So it's certain that `complete ...` would be on a new line.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: it can not use redirection because of permissions (you can not send output to a file owned by root)

Comment: Do `echo a > b; sed -i ab b` or do `echo -n a > b; sed -i ab b`, `b` would still have `a\n\b\n`.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: sure, starting sudo, and a new bash. Running just sed seems faster. The syntax is a bit weird, until you know what it is for. I am all for the sed solution now.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide I think, overhead on running new `sh` (not bash) is not so high, but the readability of `sed` usage here (which, I think, also would be slower a little bit, than running new `sh`) is much poor.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide I'm with you, it isn't that bad to use sed, as it is indeed an editor. However, the shell based solution which (at)Dmitry favorites is good as well.  Maybe the developers should just add a comment above that line which explains what they are doing and why.

Comment: Normay `sed 'a...` need a `\ ` backslash (depending OS/shell a space between a and backslash) followed by a new line than the wanted text or in this case there is nothing. Is it a specific behaviour of GNU sed (on my AIX, it doesn't work) ?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide how is sed managing to overwrite a file that you can't append to? `sed -i` just makes a tmp file and then overwrites the original with that, it's not actually editing the original file.

Comment: @EdMorton: it is run with `sudo` so it can do anything